# Return secondary array value to uipicker

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I am using a third party uipickercontroller code but I am stuck. The code returns the value from dataArr but I want it to return the value from dataArr2. Basically the cells in the picker controller show Yes or No. But when I select one I want it to return 1 or 2. Any thoughts?

```
NSArray *dataArr = @[@"YES",@"NO"];
NSArray *dataArr2 = @[@"1",@"2"];
MBZPickerView *pickerView = [[MBZPickerView alloc]initWithTitle:@"TEST" withPickerViewType:MBZPickerViewType_Normal andData:dataArr];
pickerView.font = 20.0;
pickerView.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
pickerView.buttoncolor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[pickerView showPickerView];
pickerView.block = ^(NSMutableArray *dateMutArr)
{

    weakSelf.showLb.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateMutArr[0]];
};
```

Comment: `dataArr` & `dataArr2` are sync. So if `dataArr` has unique values, then `NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:dataArr2 forKeys:dataArr]`. `NSString *selectedValue = dateMutArr[0]; weakSelf.showLb.text = dataDict[selectedValue]];`

Comment: Genius. Thank you. That was it.